# Why does the for loop only read the last element of the matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Hi I have the following code

```
for j = 1:2,

    for i = 1:24,

        for K = 1:3,

            for M = 1:3,
                PV_output(:,:,K) = real(PV_power_output(:,:,K));
                WT_output(:,:,M) =  WT_power_output(:,:,M);
                PVenergy = sum(sum(PV_output(:,:,1)));
                WTenergy = sum(sum(WT_power_output(:,:,1)));
                f = [((CRF*CC_PV)/PVenergy)+OM_PV; ((CRF*CC_WT)/WTenergy)+OM_WT];
                A = [-PV_output(j,i,K) -WT_output(j,i,M)];
                b = -Demand(j,i);
                lb = zeros(2,1);
                ub = [max_PV_area/PV_area max_WT_area/WT_area]';
            end
        end
    end
end
```

`PV_output` and `WT_output` are 365 x 24 matrices with three different sets of matrices that I am trying to examine individually..`Demand` is a 365 x 24 matrix.

When I run `linprog` it seems that it is only reading the last element of the above matrices and also when I check the size of `A` and `b` I get a 1x2 and 1x1 whereas I should be getting a 365x24x3 and 365x24

Any help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
    A = [-PV_output(j,i,K) -WT_output(j,i,M)];
```

you are assigning A to be a 1 x 2 array at every iteration. The variable returned by `-PV_output(j,i,K)` and `-WT_output(j,i,M)`  are scalars, so you should not expect A to be anything other an 1 x 2 in size.

Similarly

```
    b = -Demand(j,i);
```

simply returns a scalar element of the `Demand` matrix and so `b` has size 1 x 1.

It would appear that you wish to use these values as elements in a much larger matrix so you should assign them to the appropriate indices in your matrices A and b.

Something along the lines of

```
    b(index1,index2) = -Demand(j,i);
```

where index1 and index2 specify the position in `b` at which you want them stored. By storing the value at a particular (appropriate) element in the matrix b rather than overwriting it each time as you currently are, you should get what you want by working out the appropriate indices at each iteration. Similarly if A is 3 dimensional array then you need something similar but with 3 indices.

I cannot give you an in code solution as you have 4 loops here and it is not clear to me exactly what data you are storing. Maybe someone else can give you an exact line for line solution, but if not I hope this provides enough help for you to see what needs to be done to fix the problem.

Comment: Correct, but maybe you should give a solution instead of only pointing out the problem. +1 when amended.

Comment: PV_output(j,i,K) is a 2x24 matrix with 3 dimensions (I am looking at 3 photovoltaic manufacturers) and the hourly power output performance. WT_output is a 2x24 matrix with 3 dimensions as I am looking at the hourly power of the wind turbine for 3 manufacturers. "Demand" is a 2x24 matrix that represents the respective demand over the same time period as the PV and WT supply. This is why I have tried to use 4 loops that will give me an element by element comparison of the total supply (PV + WT) with respect to the demand over the 3 manufacturers of PV and WT.

Comment: There may be a more efficient way to do this and I would be interested for any suggestions. Hope this helps since I do need a bit more help on the coding of the question you have answered - I do understand now what the problem is but am unclear or the indexing coding side - Please let me know if you need more info on the above code to assist further

Comment: Do you suggest something like this below

Comment: In your question you say PV_output and WT_output are 365 x 24 matrices but they must be 3 dimensional as you refer to PV_Output(:,:,K).

Comment: Yes, they are 365x24 and have 3 dimensions (i.e each dimension represents a particular PV or WT manufacturer

Comment: 365 x 24 x 3 matrix you mean???? I have taken a look but it has been a few years since I last used Matlab and I cannot quite see what you want as output. I was hoping that pointing out your error would help you to fix it yourself. Hopefully you will get a better answer than mine. Sorry I could not be more help.

Comment: yes a 365x24x3 matrix. The output I am trying to get is a minimisation of the "f" using the linprog linear constrained optimisation solver. I have added an updates code below - please comment if you can

Comment: The main problem I believe I have is the Ax<=b inequality constraint. I have to match each element (in the same position) of the PV_output and WT_output with the respective element in the Demand matrix. And this has to be done over all three dimensions of each array - the question really is how does the coding look like to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```
 for j = 1:2

for i = 1:24
   for K = 1:3
      for M = 1:3

   PV_output(:,:,:) = real(PV_power_output(:,:,:));
         WT_output(:,:,:) =  WT_power_output(:,:,:);

         PVenergy = sum(sum(PV_output(:,:,1)));
         WTenergy = sum(sum(WT_power_output(:,:,1)));


          f= [((CRF*CC_PV)/PVenergy)+OM_PV; ((CRF*CC_WT)/WTenergy)+OM_WT];

         A(:,:,:) = [-PV_output(:,:,K) -WT_output(:,:,M)];


            b(:) = -Demand(j,i);

           lb = zeros(2,1);


           ub = [max_PV_area/PV_area max_WT_area/WT_area]';

      end
   end
```

end
     end

```
            x(:,:,:) = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
```